# How to convert a series of SQL execute calls into one single PLSQL code?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have a large number of SQL execute statements like so :

```
exec s535.HLVS_Verify.Check_Object('S735', 'RTDPDAH$', 'PACKAGE BODY');
exec s535.HLVS_Verify.Check_Object('S735', 'RTDPDAH$JS$PKG_DATA_ACQ_HIST', 'PACKAGE');
```

And I am trying to convert this into PLSQL :

How to structure this ?

Could I just put this all in the BEGIN section of a standard PLSQL block ?

thanks

Comment: remove exec from all lines and enclose then between BEGIN...END, thats it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you have exception logging in each of the objects being called.It is as simple as below,

If you intent to run from SQL prompt,

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
BEGIN

 s535.HLVS_Verify.Check_Object('S735', 'RTDPDAH$', 'PACKAGE BODY'); 
 s535.HLVS_Verify.Check_Object('S735', 'RTDPDAH$JS$PKG_DATA_ACQ_HIST', 'PACKAGE');

END;
```

PS: In case you are using any tool that doesn't support SQL*Plus command just remove SET `SERVEROUTPUT ON` from the above.

If you would like to have a stored object like a stored procedure,

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MASTER_PROCEDURE 
    AS 
     BEGIN

         s535.HLVS_Verify.Check_Object('S735', 'RTDPDAH$', 'PACKAGE BODY'); 
         s535.HLVS_Verify.Check_Object('S735', 'RTDPDAH$JS$PKG_DATA_ACQ_HIST', 'PACKAGE');


END;
```

Comment: thanks !  for some reason I'm getting an ERROR at the `SET SERVEROUTPUT ON` line,

Comment: These wouldn't be separated by a comma though ?